# nginx root does not seem to be working on Mac

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew

I installed nginx via hombrew on the mac:

"brew nginx"

whenever try to start the server, I notice that a lot of the path configured in the nginx config is not working.  It's appending the nginx prefix to all the root paths.

I'm still new to setting up nginx so please bear with me.

In this case homebrew nginx is configured by default to be in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.0/
```

Let's say the folder structure is /test/nginx

```
http {
    client_body_temp_path      ./nginx/temp/client_body_temp;

    server {
        root /test;
     ...
     }
}
```

in this case, I would expect /test/./nginx/temp.client_body_temp to be correct.  However, in the error it complains about not finding

```
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.0/./nginx/temp/client_body_temp
```

Any idea of how to resolve this with either reconfiguring the prefix or having the correct root be picked up?

Thanks